# Batch: goto was unexpected at this time error

Tags: batch-file

So im making a project for school and i want to goto menu if the user input is not valid
My code is this:

```
:menu  
echo.  
echo.  
echo What would you like to know first?
echo.
echo.
echo 1) Salary
echo 2) What Do they do?
echo 3) Schools near me that offer game design programs
echo 4) Requirements
echo 5) Credits
echo.
echo.
set /p choice="Enter Number: "
if %choice% == 1 goto salary
if %choice% == 2 goto do
if %choice% == 3 goto schools
if %choice% == 4 goto req
if %choice% == 5 goto credits
goto menu
```

when i enter input, there is a line that flashes
Goto was unexpected at this time then exits
What am i doing wrong?
I should add that my input is not a valid option. (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Goto was unexpected at this time batch windows 7 starter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775644/goto-was-unexpected-at-this-time-batch-windows-7-starter)

Answer (score 4):

```
if %choice% == 1 goto salary
```

Imagine, what this would do, when `%choice%` is empty. The line would then be read as:

```
if  == 1 goto salary
```

Obviously a syntax error. "goto was unexpected".

To avoid this, use

```
if "%choice%" == "1" goto salary
```

This would be read as:

```
if "" == "1" goto salary
```

Syntax is ok now.