# Batch File 'if " "goto " " Not working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, command, echo, goto

I was creating a batch game, and I had a previous game I made so I could remember stuff from the code.

On the game I was working on the If and Goto command where not working. So I testing my previous game, and it worked fine with things like that. So I created This:

```
@echo off   
title test
:1
cls
echo testing Testing 123
echo Type Go
set /p 123=
if %123% == Go goto 2
if %123% == go goto 2
:3
echo Gone wrong :(
pause
exit
:2
cls
echo Worked
pause
exit
```

And When I type `Go` It says `Gone Wrong :(`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Well, I tried that but the same thing happens :(

Comment: `if` has a `/i` switch to ignore capitalizaion. And you should also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22946040/2152082) to avoid syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You *never* should use a variable with a name that start in digit:

```
if %123% == Go goto 2
```

In previous line `%1` is replaced by the first parameter of the Batch file, so the real comparison is:

```
if 23 == Go goto 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off   
title test
:1
cls
echo testing Testing 123
echo Type Go
set /p _123=
if %_123% == Go goto 2
if %_123% == go goto 2
:3
echo Gone wrong :(
pause
exit
:2
cls
echo Worked
pause
exit
```

`%1` is taken for the first argument to the script.You can also use delayed expansion:

```
@echo off  
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion 
title test
:1
cls
echo testing Testing 123
echo Type Go
set /p 123=

if !123! == Go goto :2
if !123! == go goto :2
:3
echo Gone wrong :(
pause
exit
:2
cls
echo Worked
pause
exit /b
```